# Concurrent read/write on tokio TcpStream

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a scenario where thread 1 writes to the socket, thread 2 reads from the socket. I have done this in the past via `split()` which would consume the TcpStream and return the ReadHalf/WriteHalf, which then could be neatly passed to the threads. I am running into issues on 1.39.0(tokio - 0.2.0-alpha.6).

1. Now it has changed to `pub fn split(&mut self) -> (ReadHalf, WriteHalf)`. This doesn't allow passing the ReadHalf/WriteHalf(whose lifetime is tied to the stream) to separate threads, without running into messy lifetime issues
2. The plain `read()/write()` variants take `&mut self`, which makes it impossible to do concurrent reads/writes.

Interestingly, UdpSocket still has the old way(`pub fn split(self) -> (UdpSocketRecvHalf, UdpSocketSendHalf)`)

Also found this related(unresolved) thread: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/1108. Not sure it is even possible anymore with TcpStream.

Appreciate any suggestions here.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `tokio::io::split` free function instead. This change was introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/1521).

Comment: Thanks @edwardw, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tokio::io::split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/tokio/io/fn.split.html)

```rust
let (read, write) = tokio::io::split(socket);
```

This ends into [`ReadHalf`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/tokio/io/struct.ReadHalf.html) and [`WriteHalf`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/tokio/io/struct.WriteHalf.html), both of which implement `Send` and `Sync`.